# Symfony 4 => 5 : Problem with ApiPlatform

Tags: symfony, symfony5, symfony-4.4

I'm trying to upgrade a project from Symfony 4.4 to 5. I have a problem with api-platform/core package.

I updated all symfony/* package to 4.4.* to 5.0.* and updated api_platform/core from 2.6 to 2.6.5

When I run composer update --with-all-dependencies it returns :

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "5.0.*"
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires api-platform/core ^2.6.5 -> satisfiable by api-platform/core[v2.6.5].
    - api-platform/core v2.6.5 requires symfony/http-foundation ^4.4 || ^5.1 -> found symfony/http-foundation[v4.4.0, ..., v4.4.30, v5.1.0, ..., v5.3.7] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
```

Thanx for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> api-platform/core v2.6.5 requires symfony/http-foundation ^4.4 || ^5.1

...this obviously forbids using Symfony 5.0 with `api-platform/core`.

---

Also, Symfony 5.0 is out of support since over a year. Please consider using a supported version of Symfony, like 5.3

Comment: I wanted to upgrade 4.4 to 5.0, after 50. to 5.1, ... :) I try to ugrade to 5.3. thanx